# Can I change a value in the url from true to false

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't want to reload I just want to change the value in the url as follows:

```
http://localhost:3000/boards/10?show_customize=true
```

to

```
http://localhost:3000/boards/10?show_customize=false
```

Can I do this with jquery or javascript?

Comment: If you change the URL, the page needs to reload. There's nothing you can do about that (Exception: The Hash part `#`) what do you want to do?

Comment: @Pekka You can do it in HTML5

Comment: @Jleagle ah, fair enough. Damn you, technical progress!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [pushState()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)

```
window.history.pushState({state:'new'},'New State','http://localhost:3000/boards/10?show_customize=false');
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible with the history API in the modern browsers using the `pushState` method. Here is an [explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#section_6).